# MySQL Error 1064 (42000). Insert failure on MySQL table

Tags: mysql

i am making chatting software in which whenever a new friend is made the details are added in current users friend table. similar insert queries are working for other purposes but when used for this it shows syntax error.
so please help me out. also do tell me while showing error it shows whatsapp_friends as table name which is my other table but not 9636354343_whatsapp_friends.

```
INSERT INTO 9636354343_ whatsapp_friends  (friend_no ,friend_name )  
VALUES (1111111111,'gurmeet');
```

[image: the image describes my table and error]

Comment: thx. for your help.

Comment: yes thx. again as i was searching for the problem for last 2  hours.

Comment: sure no problem

Comment: @Vérace OP forgot to ping you ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Please check [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) to see why posting images of text is not a good idea (can't cut and paste!).
- **Always** put the error code in your question's Title. Easier to search, easier to find!
- Also, use the "Code sample" tool for code, not the "Block Quote".
- Finally, and to answer your question, your SQL appears to have an error - the name of the table you are querying is `"9636354343_ whatsapp_friends"` and not `"9636354343_whatsapp_friends"` - i.e. your code as posted has a space between the first underscore and the "whatsapp" part. 
   
  Always give a `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table\G` (as text) with table definitions.

In MySQL, you can have [64 characters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) in identifiers! That_is_more_than_enough_dont_you_think? (=40 characters!). I know what you did was an error, but MySQL (and other servers) do allow you to have spaces in identifiers, but putting the names in backticks (`) or double-quotes (") or whatever.

I cannot stress enough what madness this is - [hic sunt leones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_be_dragons)!. Developers will always be asking "[Is that | Should that be] a space? "Is it a typo"? What happens if you accidentally put in **two** spaces - can be tricky to read **and especially debug**! Continue as you are doing, and **use underscores** to split identifiers to make them more readable!

Also, if you are in a multi-developer shop, pick a few conventions (you can Google [best practices](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sql%20naming%20conventions%20best%20practices&t=ffab&ia=qa)) and **stick** to them! Table names (singular or plural). Upper or Lower case - some servers enforce, others don't (with and/or without escaping).

I (for example, and this is just me) **always** use singular table names (with the obvious exception of [`order`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sql%20naming%20conventions%20best%20practices&t=ffab&ia=qa)) and lower case for my identifiers, `UPPER case FOR my SQL;` - it makes it easy to pick out the language parts from your own objects.

Finally, no matter what you do, you should **always** use the [comments](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) facility available for tables and columns to let other developers know what the table/field is for and if they need to know anything special about the name, if it's not in accord with your convention!

p.s. welcome to the forum! p.p.s you can let people know you've replied to them by using @ in the text of your comment, i.e. for me, it's @Vérace!